# There is no "Advanced Settings" button in Oauth

Tags: google-api, youtube-data-api, google-docs-api

(The check will not pass, because for an example of work you need a list of sponsors of the YouTuber) The YouTuber who needs to log in when he tries does not show him the "Advanced Settings" button

[image: When he tries to log in] and

[image: When I log in]

Comment: sry, i use a translator, and if something is not right - do not scold

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [ask] edit your question describe what it is you are doing show your code [example] and describe the error. Please change your browser language so these error messages appear in English.